# Re-Drawing things on canvas alters old drawing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

**--- SOLUTION ---**

After a very long time reasearching, trying and saving image data all over my drive, I found a solution for my problem. I will write the solution in here for these facing similar problems like me.

The problem was the way I saved the images to undo or redo things. For this I took the drawing layer, converted it to an .png base64, drew this base64 onto my background and saved my background as .png base64 again in an array. From this array I would read with the undo/redo function.

The problem is, that with every conversation from canvas -> png the lines alter. So it is to minimize the amount of times we use .toDataURL().

I realized then that for .drawImage() you dont need an base64 string as parameter. You just can pass the canvas containing the image to draw. Like this we dont have to do the png conversion and wont even get to the point where the lines get fatter and fatter. Like this there is only one conversion, and that is at the final export of the canvas to .png or .jpg.

I hope someone else can use my findings and does not have to go through the struggle I had to.

---

**--- ORIGINAL PROBLEM ---**

I am trying to build my own drawing app. It is based on attrament.js, an existing library which does exactly this already. I am now trying to add new features to it.

I made an system with which you can undo/redo changes. For this I have 2 seperate canvas, one which is empty and on which I draw, and on the other one are all previous paths drawn. On end draw everything from the drawing canvas gets copied onto the background canvas with canvas.toDataURL() -> canvas.drawImage.

My main problem is now, when the image gets copied onto the background canvas, everything on the background canvas gets "fattened" a little bit.

[image: Fatter to smaller]

As you can see it gets slightly fatter from the left to the right. Everything was drawn with the same brush and size, but everytime i stopped the previous drawings were fattened a bit.

Has anyone else already faced this problem? Why do these lines get fatter and fatter? And how can I prevent these line from getting fatter?

Thanks for the help!

Edit 1:

I created a JSFiddle and while creating it I realised that it has something to do with the scale. The JSFiddle is a horrible hack, but I was not able to include the .js, so i put it into the script part.

Try changing the scale in the html `<script>` tag, the higher it is the more they get fatter.

```
<script>
// Scale the canvas for higher pixel density
var scale = 1;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h7jfpu3n/37/

The JSFiddle does not seem to work on Edge. Cant tell you really why, but on Firefox it has no problems.

Comment: They are all the same width when testing on OSX, Firefox v. 49.0.1.

This seems like a browser bug to me.